# Sort table function works only once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a football league table done in HTML that updates each time I simulate a match with a system of dropdowns and inputs. That system works fine, and updates the values of the corresponding team in the league table.
The problem is that when those values in the table are updated, the function of sorting the table is called, but it does not work at all. The function is the following one:

```
function SortTable()
        {
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
            table = document.getElementById("liga123");
            switching = true;

            /* Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done */
            while (switching)
            {
                /* Start with no switching */
                switching = false;
                rows = table.rows;

                /* Loop through all table rows except the first one, which is the heading */
                for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++)
                {
                    /* Start saying there should be not switching */
                    shouldSwitch = false;

                    /* Get 2 elements to compare, one from current row and another from the next one */
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];

                    /* Check if those 2 rows should switch */
                    if (x.innerHTML() < y.innerHTML())
                    {
                        /* Switch, restore the hierarchy by points and break */
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                        break;
                    }
                    if (x.innerHTML() == y.innerHTML())
                    {
                        /* Change the hierarchy to Goals Difference */
                        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];
                        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[8];

                        if (x.innerHTML() < y.innerHTML())
                        {
                            /* Switch, restore the hierarchy by points and break */
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                            break;
                        }
                        if (x.innerHTML() == y.innerHTML())
                        {
                            /* Change the hierarchy to Goals in Favour */
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];
                            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[6];

                            if (x.innerHTML() < y.innerHTML())
                            {
                                /* Switch, restore the hierarchy by points and break */
                                shouldSwitch = true;
                                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                break;
                            }
                            if (x.innerHTML() == y.innerHTML())
                            {
                                /* Change the hierarchy to Victories */
                                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[3];
                                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[3];

                                if (x.innerHTML() < y.innerHTML())
                                {
                                    /* Switch, restore the hierarchy by points and break */
                                    shouldSwitch = true;
                                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (x.innerHTML() == y.innerHTML())
                                {
                                    /* Change the hierarchy to Loses */
                                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];
                                    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[5];

                                    if (x.innerHTML() > y.innerHTML())
                                    {
                                        /* Switch, restore the hierarchy by points and break */
                                        shouldSwitch = true;
                                        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[9];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch)
                {
                /* If a change must be done, do it and mark it */
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then, when that function is called it is supposed to go through all the rows in the table and sorting first by more points.
That "hierarchy" system works like this: If 2 teams has the same points, then it sorts by goals difference. If the goals difference of both teams are the same, then it sorts by goals in favour and, if that is not enough, it sorts by victories and, finally, by loses.
My problem is that the function is supposed to work after each match, but no sorting is done. I am doing anything bad? I did not posted the league table because those are around 300 lines, but if that is needed I will do it.
By the way, my code has all the IDs and comments in Spanish, so maybe I forgot to edit some of them

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. And please create a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, I did not had in mind using the browser controls. It appeared that the problem was that I writed "x.innerHTML()" instead of "x.innerHTML"... what a fail. Thanks!

Comment: Some advice: Instead of all these heavily nested `if` statements, it'd be a lot more beneficial for you to convert these data rows into objects, and apply it to an array (or subsets of an array). Then sort this array by either 1 or more property values. This code can be reworked and simplified quite a bit, resulting in cleaner code and speed. Perhaps post some HTML and a JSFiddle so we can view and assist w/ a better, practical solution

Comment: I just copied all my code in a JSFiddle but that was like around 5000 lines, so I took out a div that contained a calendar of all matches played and everything it used, so the whole code got reduced to 824 lines. There will be things with no sense, like a dropdown with only one option, but that was to show or the league table or the matches played history. Also, most comments and IDs are in Spanish, as I am from Spain, but I could change something if needed. The code is here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/charlyvm_/c9qvk62w/9/) @RobScott